# Volume Shadow Copy not Working on HP MediaSmart Server

Tags: windows-home-server, shadow-copy, hp-mediasmart

I've got an HP MediaSmart EX485 server running at home which is seemingly working great, with potentially one exception: shadow copies don't seem to exist. This isn't a huge deal, but would be nice to have it enabled as files on the server's shares are the only copies (Yes, I'm backing up, but let's keep that out of the equation.).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> It turns out that there’s a bug in the
>   way VSS is handled on servers with two
>   or more drives. On such servers, it’s
>   possible that “Previous Versions” will
>   be shown, but will be inaccessible or
>   a “Cannot copy : Invalid
>   file handle” error message will be
>   displayed when attempting to copy or
>   restore a previous version of a file
>   or folder.
>
> There’s also a loosely related bug
>   which only affects **HP** and other
>   OEM servers. Because of the way the
>   servers are prepared for duplication,
>   VSS is turned off when they are
>   shipped from the factory.
>
> On the **HP MediaSmart Server** VSS is
>   turned off for all partitions.

[Source](http://mswhs.com/2008/03/27/volume-shadow-services-vss-on-whs/)

Comment: Not the solution I want, but an answer I'll take!